# Where are SSIS Packages Saved?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I right clicked on a Database in the object explorer of SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. I went to Tasks > Import Data, and imported some data from a flat text file, opting to save the package on the server.

Now how the heck do I get to the package to edit or run it again? Where in SQL Server Management Studio do I go? I've expanded everything and I can't find it. It's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you connect to the Integration Services instance on the server (different choice in the dropdown from "Database Engine" when you connect in SQL Server Management Studio), they'll be under the MSDB folder under Stored Packages.

Comment: I tried this. There are two root folders. Running Packages and Stored Packages. Both of those and every subfolder is empty.

However, if I go through my import process again, it will tell me the package exists and ask if I want to overwrite, so I know they must be on the server!

I double-checked and I am connecting to the correct server.

Comment: Oh wait I do see them there! But there is no option to Edit. Just Import, Export, Upgrade, etc.

Comment: You can't edit them on the Integration Services instance itself.  You'll need to export them and then open them up in BIDS (Business Intelligence Design Studio, the Visual Studio flavor for BI), and then you can redeploy the package.

Comment: Unbelievable how convoluted the process of making a small edit to a package is. In my experience, its almost always easier to fire up the Import/Export wizard and redo the entire thing. I miss DTS.

Comment: There is no option to connect to "Integration Services", or anything even remotely like it. The options are "Database Engine" and "SQL Server Compact". I am so utterly sick and tired of fighting with this steaming pile of crap.

Comment: @Martha You could as well have saved the package to the file system immediately. No need to connect to the "Integration Services" (which I think you're missing because of your SQL Server SKU)

Answer (score 6):

When you start management studio and connect to a database, make sure you have the server type set to **Integration Services** instead of **Database Engine**.

Comment: I can't see the option to connect to Integration Services in my copy of management studio? but I can find the stored procedure in the execute package utility?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the file path in SSIS under "properties" of the package. 
right click the package in solution explorer > full path in the properties window

Answer (score 1):

They are stored on the file system as .dtsx files or in msdb.dbo.sysssispackages.  If they are stored in the database you can run them with sql server management studio by connecting to integration services.  To edit them, you'll need to export to the file system (.dtsx file) then edit.