# Is it possible to recover the SSIS packages that are deployed in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have developed few SSIS packages in my local system and deployed it in to remote SQL Server. Now my local hard disk crashed. Is there a way to get back the packages that are deployed to SQL Server?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are SSIS Packages Saved?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740735/where-are-ssis-packages-saved)

Comment: similar but not the same question, nor the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the server itself, you or somebody with the appropriate permissions can login to the server that is running SQL Server Integration Services, from there you can open SSMS, connect to Integration Services, and export any package that has been deployed to that server.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:
1) Start integration services project.
2) Right click, Add existing package. 
3) Select SSIS Package store. 
4) Type the name of the remote server. 
5) You can import any package locally from the remote server.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Project Deployment Model...

Open Visual Studio

Create a new Project but do not click the Integration Services project that is in the default Business Intelligence section. Instead, expand BI and click Integration Services. From there, use the Integration Services Import Project Wizard.

[image]

Point that to your SSISDB or an existing .ispac file and it will import the project, parameters and project level connection managers.